# How to make a link to download a server file on the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdf

I am trying to create a simple download link

The file I want to download is a `.pdf` that the user can upload, and now I want to make it possible to download. With the pop-up box, you know, or just on the chrome download bar

I've tried what every answer says:

```
<a href="<?=$GUIDELINES_PDF_DIR . $projectId . '.pdf'?>" download="guidelines.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

But that leads to "Failed - no file", even though when I check

```
 if(file_exists($GUIDELINES_PDF_DIR . $projectId . '.pdf'))
```

it returns true!

Some other notes:

- I'm pretty shaky on server things, so maybe the same link doesn't work on PHP and on HTML? In that case, how can I find the file?
- This link is within a `<form>`, so I don't really want to create another `<form>` inside it, or do anything that compromises the info that the user has inputed

Thank so much :)

Comment: Is `$GUIDELINES_PDF_DIR` the path in the server or accessible through web?

Comment: Are you able to access the file from your browser if you navigate to `https://host/path/to/pdf/guidelines.pdf`? Also, is `$GUIDELINES_PDF_DIR` an absolute or relative path?

Comment: @frz3993 I just checked and it doesn't seem to be accessible. If I put it on the browser it's "not found"

Comment: @JimNilsson oh it's relative, I think! It doens't contain the server location, and it starts with '/'. If I put it on the browser, it says it cannot be found :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$GUIDELINES_PDF_DIR` is a directory on your server's hard disk.

The resulting path you are creating is relative to the root of your server's hard disk and not to the DocumentRoot of your web server.

You need to account for that difference when generating your URL.

Comment: Omg... After so much time looking, it all made sense after reading your answer! Thank you so much, the link works now :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a right headers:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");
```

Comment: I'm a little confused... How does the link interact with this? If the user clicks to download the pdf, how should I call this code?

Comment: That's not going to help if the file isn't found

Comment: Also the URL points directly to a PDF file so you can't just add PHP code to it.